# extract text from several html tags inside same div in lxml python

Tags: python, lxml

I'm new in lxml and python, and I don't find how can I extract text from several html tags (a,div,...) inside the same div and make it with lxml (python).

**Example of code:**

```
 <div class=owner>

    <a href="big/site" class="first">First text I want</a>
    <div class="second">Second text I want</div>   
    <a href="much/money" rel="bookmark">Third text I want</a>      

 </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the criteria for selecting the text? Does `tree.xpath('//div[@class="owner"]/*/text()')` work in your case?

Comment: No doesn't work. I don't have any criteria

Comment: Works fine for your example... Is your real data different? You'll need to adjust the xpath to match your document structure...

Comment: I'll keep trying, thanks